# Twilio generic error when outgoing connection is disconnecting

Tags: android, twilio

```
//Hang up the call
if( phoneVariable.connection != null ) {
phoneVariable.connection.disconnect();
phoneVariable.connection = null;
}
```

generic error shows, I try everything but doesn't work for me .